# pythonic way to replace special char at beginning or at the end of string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a string like this `'- 36 x 45 x 2.75-size-'`. I want to remove special chars at the beginning of this string (' ', '-', etc). I have implemented a dirty way of achieving this

```
    lis1 = []
>>> flag = True
>>> for x in str1:
...   if flag and x=='-':
...     flag = False
...   else:
...     lis1.append(x)
... 
>>> lis1
[' ', '3', '6', ' ', 'x', ' ', '4', '5', ' ', 'x', ' ', '2', '.', '7', '5', '-', 'k', 'd', 'j', 'd', 'f', 'n', 'd', '-']
>>> ''.join(lis1)
' 36 x 45 x 2.75-size-'
```

But I am looking for a more efficient/ optimised way to achieve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`str.lstrip()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.lstrip) to remove a set of characters from the start:

```
str1 = str1.lstrip(' -')
```

The argument is treated as a *set*, so *any* character that appears in that string is going to be removed from the start, until the first characters of the string no longer appears in the argument.

In the above example, any spaces or `-` dashes are removed from the start, in whatever order they appear:

```
>>> str1 = '- 36 x 45 x 2.75-size-'
>>> str1.lstrip(' -')
'36 x 45 x 2.75-size-'
```

There are corresponding [`str.rstrip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rstrip)  and [`str.strip()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) methods (remove from the end of the string or both ends, respectively).

Comment: Facepalm moment for me. Thanks for reminding me of this function. I think I need to focus more before posting such questions